# Spring mvc filter doesn't take effect

Tags: java, spring-mvc, filter

I'm learning SpringMVC. The version I use is 4.2.5.RELEASE. The filter I configure in `web.xml` doesn't seem to work

**Server**: Tomcat 7

**Problem** : When I use the `GET` method to pass in Chinese parameters, even if I configure the filter for UTF-8 encoding conversion, but the string I get is still garbled

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I consider my configuration is not wrong

`Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getInfo(HttpServletRequest request,
                      @RequestParam("username") String username, Model model) {

    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(username, "xxx", "xxx");
    Logger.i(userInfo.toString());
    model.addAttribute("info", userInfo);
    return "user/info";
}
```

When I pass in the Chinese parameters, the information printed by the console is garbled, and it is garbled to return to the front.
And `request.getCharacterEncoding()` return is "UTF-8"

But when i use:

```
try {
    username = new String(username.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It can display normally.

So I changed the default encoding of Tomcat and changed it to UTF-8. After that, even if I don't perform transcoding in the code, I can get the correct parameters.

**Question**: So I am very puzzled that the filter has no effect.

I would like to express my heartfelt thanks for your enthusiasm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried configuring Tomcat's `server.xml`? Try setting `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute to a `Connector` component:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIencoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

You can get more information [here](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding)